# Creating Android Transparent Layout in Custom Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, transparent, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have written a Custom Dialog, which works perfectly fine.

```
public class GalleryAlertDialog extends Dialog {}
```

In a class I call the class with the

```
dialog.show();
```

I want to achieve this look:

[image]

I need the button over the dialog,like this.

However, this is what I get:

[image]

Here's the layout xml's part where I declare the layout and the button inside it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llContainer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_buttonContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_popupclose"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:tag="btn_close" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_pagerContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_buttonContainer"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
            android:background="@color/white" />

       <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tbFavorite"
                    android:layout_width="35dip"
                    android:layout_height="35dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_check"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn="" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ff212121"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContactFullName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@color/seperator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContactFullName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCompany"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPosition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

.....

I tried giving the ll_buttonContainer a transparent background programatically too.

```
llButtonContainer.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
    R.color.transparent_tr));

llButtonContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

I even tried

```
        android:background="null"
```

Nothing works. The layout is still visible, it gets any color (red, yellow, white etc.) other than transparent. Is this how it works, will I not be able to give it transparent background due to how Dialog works?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us your whole xml please, the problem can be in the parent of the LinearLayout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself.

I found this line on StackOverFlow, tried it and it worked.
Writing this line,

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

just before

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Hope this helps some one and you won't suffer as much as I do. It's pretty simple, but very annoying if you miss it.

Comment: Where did you find "this line on StackOverflow"? Do you have a link to the original?

Comment: I was new to StackOverflow at the time and didn't post a link, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Use this Style into yout res/values/style

making WindowTranparent

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">#03afee
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
   </style>
```

Apply this to your Dialog...

Comment: nit, thanks for your answer.

I used 

style="@style/Theme.Transparent"

in the LinearLayout of my custom Dialog xml, but no luck there. The container layout of the button still has white background instead of transparent.

Comment: @lev add your background ="@null" and for image use android:src

Comment: I tried to  set the background to null on the button container LinearLayout, the main layout of the xml file and even the button.

Still no luck.

Comment: @lev show some more xml content...also set  null value to ImageButton background & use src for image not background attribute

Comment: I added the whole xml file to the original question.

Comment: I could not get the desired results using this approach as color/transparent was not completely transparent. had to use dialog instead

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:background="#00000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ad_view_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/closeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>




in dialog 




final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ad_view);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
                ImageView closeBtn = ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeButton));

                ImageView addView=((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ad_view_image));
                addView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                addView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(marketlink.startsWith("http")){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(marketlink));
                    mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    }
                    });
            }
```